# Determine which expression was not true in if-statement in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
infile = new FileInfo(inputFilename);
outfile = new FileInfo(outputFilename);

if (!infile.Exists || !outfile.Exists) {
  Console.WriteLine("File missing: " + ???);
}
```

Is it possible to determine which of the single "if statements" was not true? `???` shall be replaced with the filename of the non-existing file.

Comment: You could use two booleans to test and check later whether it is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just split your `if` into two?

```
if (!infile.Exists) {
  Console.WriteLine("File missing: " + infile);
}
if (!outfile.Exists) {
  Console.WriteLine("File missing: " + outfile);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I will go. Just though that maybe there exists another possibility if more than just two expressions are checked. It's ok for two :-)

Comment: @Robert There is nothing *built in*. Btw. with two separate `if` you'll get two messages when both files don't exist. With your one `if` you'd get only one.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the files that do not exist and then use that collection to print the error message. For example:

```
var missingFiles = new FileInfo[] {inFile, outFile}.Where(f => !f.Exists);
foreach (var missingFile in missingFiles) {
    Console.WriteLine("File missing: " + missingFile);
}
```

Comment: @L.B Thanks for the correction. Fixed it. (Using mostly Java, Scala nowadays.)

Comment: Sorry, Now *missingFiles* is `IEnumerable<bool>` not `IEnumerable<string>` giving the file name.

Comment: @Weston what is the use of `.Select(f => f)` ?

Comment: @L.B No idea, it was late! Maybe was confusing with the "from...where...select" form as that always needs a select.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly. However, you could write

```
bool infileExists = infile.Exists;
bool outfileExists = outfile.Exists;
if (!infileExists || !outfileExists) {
  Console.WriteLine("File missing: " + infileExists?"Outfile":"Infile");
}
```

This doesn't even need an additional evaluation of the property.